# Twitter @Anywhere not working in phonegap application

Tags: cordova, twitter, sencha-touch-2, twitter-anywhere

I'm currently developing a phonegap application that uses Sencha Touch.
I have a share to Twitter panel set up with uses the [Twitter @anywhere Tweet Box](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#tweetbox) (see image).

[image: How Twitter @Anywhere looks when it works]

When I test my app in Safari and Mobile Safari on the device, this loads as displayed. However, when I build my app using Phonegap and proceed to load this panel, the tweet box does not load.

My question is why does this not work as it should?

Finally, please note that in my phonegap application I have the external hosts set to allow content from any external site (my app loads content from youtube and this does work).

Comment: If you take a look at your logcat, what is the error displayed?